# ScriptableObject data modified from code in editor mode, but containing asset file not changed

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have a **ScriptableObject** reference in a **MonoBehaviour** class.

Modify its values with **CustomEditor** button.

Save It.

Values seems changed.
Even selected **ScriptableObject** Inspector displays data modified.

But asset file on disk don't have any data.
And there's no data available from code of any another **MonoBehaviour** instance.

Here is a code snippet used to save my **ScriptableObject**.

```
public TextAsset text;
[SerializeField]
//Thats My Scriptable Object
public PathFramesList pathFramesList;
[SerializeField]
public List<List<ICurveData>> frameDatasList = new List<List<ICurveData>>();
// Called By CustomEditor Button
public void ReadData()
{
    #region BlahBlahBlah generating some data to save

    var separator = new string[] { "%" };
    var framesUnparsedData = text.text.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (var f in framesUnparsedData)
        frameDatasList.Add(ParseFrame(f));
    var result = new ICurveData[frameDatasList.Count][];
    for (int i = 0; i < frameDatasList.Count; i++)
        result[i] = frameDatasList[i].ToArray();

    #endregion

    #region Trying to save data

    pathFramesList.frameDatasList = result; // Set data to object
    EditorUtility.SetDirty(pathFramesList); // Even This didn't help
    AssetDatabase.SaveAssets(); // Looks it doesn't work
    AssetDatabase.Refresh(); // Hoped this will help, whatever it do

    #endregion

}
```

And that's my **ScriptableObjectClass**
And Its **CustomEditor**

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "ParsedPathData", menuName = "Create Path Data Asset")]
[System.Serializable]
public class PathFramesList : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    public ICurveData[][] frameDatasList;
}

#if UNITY_EDITOR
[CustomEditor(typeof(PathFramesList))]
public class PathFramesListEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        PathFramesList pathFrameList = (PathFramesList)target;
        if(pathFrameList.frameDatasList == null)
        {
            GUILayout.TextField("Frames Count is 0");
        }
        else
        {
            // It still has all data
            GUILayout.TextField("Frames Count is " + pathFrameList.frameDatasList.Length, 200);
        }
        if(GUILayout.Button("SaveAsset"))
        {
            // Tried to force saving with this) Didn't help
            
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(serializedObject.targetObject);
            serializedObject.Update();
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
            AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Looks like scriptable objects files just can't store interface implementations examples.

Any else data was written to file well,

Correct me, please, if i'm wrong.